# HTML5 в браузерах - Как быстрее отрисовываются картинки из текста?

Tags: html5, svg

Как проверить, картинка на веб-странице быстрее отрисовывается, если её закодировать в base64 или из SVG? Нужна картинка в текстовом виде.

Comment: вы растр в svg кодировать собрались?

Comment: Взять две большие картинки примерно одинакового размера в байтах, вставить их на страницу и смотреть во вкладку таймлайн.

Comment: Только где взять эти картинки, чтобы их загрузка длилась хоть сколько-нибудь значительное время?

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов svg-картинка 141 КБ http://simplemaps.com/static/demos/resources/svg-library/svgs/world.svg, дальше берёте любой пнг, конвертируете и смотрите, чтобы результат был примерно такой же в КБ.

Comment: Base64 дольше рендерится

Comment: @JK_Action именно что *рендерится* дольше SVG.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko https://soundcloud.com/web-standards/episode-56

Comment: @JK_Action и что дальше? я читал эти статьи, но незадача в том, что они о другом. результаты реального исследования с разбивкой по процессу/времени есть в моём ответе и исходя из этих данных именно *рендеринг* быстрее, но на общую сумму времени это почти никак не влияет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плюс один **base64** в вашем html или css - минус одно **http**-соединение. Думаю пояснять не надо, но на всяк почитайте [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/116538/).

Answer (score 2):

Взял две картинки, одну [SVG](http://simplemaps.com/static/demos/resources/svg-library/svgs/world.svg) 140 КБ, другую — обычный JPG, габариты 743×498, Save for web 70%. Джипег вставил в базовый HTML, пропустил через base64-кодер и получил итоговый размер страницы 140 КБ.

Для каждой страницы сделал несколько итераций с очисткой кэша и аппаратной перезагрузкой. Последние данные приведены для SVG-картинки с изменёнными размерами, чтобы они были такие же, как у джипега, потому что в процессе возникла идея, что это может как-то влиять на скорость.

Результаты в Developer Tools / Timeline такие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интерпретировать эти данные предлагаю вам самостоятельно, потому что мне эта разница кажется на грани погрешности.

Исходные данные: Хром 56, виндовс 7, ОЗУ 4, core i5.